# customize "Chosen" plugin for a specific select box

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I want to insert the Chosen plugin to a specific post in a wordpress site. This is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $('select:not(#mo-fonts)').chosen({ width:"95%" });
});
```

```html
<select class="Nom"> 
  <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
```

I don't know what I have to change in the jQuery script to specify the plugin just for this select box (not other select box). I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $('Nom').chosen({ width:"95%" });
});
```

Comment: Assuming you want to make the `select` width `95%` of the container you can just use CSS: `.Nom { width: 95%; }`

Comment: no ,  i don t want to change style , i want to specify a pulgin to a select box : )

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a correct selector to match the select element. This should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $('select.Nom').chosen({ width:"95%" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do somethig, change your html like this

```
<select class="Nom" id="special-select"> 
  <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
```

and let's work with that id

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#special-select').chosen({ width:"95%" });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thannnnnnks my firends 
Finally it has worked ^^ !! 
Thank you a lot your answers were helpful ^^
(my problem it was that I make changes of scripts of an another page, so when I refresh my page in the navigator I get the same result )